# export SQL database schema into MsExcel file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

HI I need to export Database Schema from SQL Server management studio express 2005 into MSExcel? generate script is giving me the script. but i need to have Excel file contains database schema. how do i do with SQL server management studio express 2005?

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is use this script to get all the table data, and copy-paste the results to an Excel file:

```
SELECT o.name AS TableName
    , c.name AS ColumnName
    , t.name AS DataType
    , c.Max_Length
    , c.Precision
    , c.Scale
FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE type = 'U'
ORDER BY
    o.name 
    , c.name
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately I am not too familiar with SQL server 2005
How about Import and Export Wizard?
The wizard should have the option to select destination type